# Changing the registry key permission using RegSetKeySecurity in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I am writing a registry cleaner app.
I need to delete some secure registry key values, but due to their access permission my delete operation is failing.

I learned that the registry access permissions can be removed using [RegSetKeySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Method.

But I am not sure of how to set SECURITY_INFORMATION and PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR parameters rightly to set the security of key to user level.

Will appreciate if anyone can guide me on how to move forward.

Comment: Please don't write another registry cleaner. They do nothing but cause trouble.

Comment: Dont worry. Its just for learning purpose. I wont sell it to you. ;)

Comment: You do realize that in order to change the access permissions to user level, you have to already be running as an administrator (which means you wouldn't need to change the access permissions in order to delete)?

Comment: @KenWhite My app is running with Admin privileges but some keys just won't delete still. Guess they are locked with some System level security or something which we can change using RegSetKeySecurity , just dont know how.

Comment: Ok. Not sure what your actual question is, though. The docs you link explain the parameters; you get the Security Descriptor through `InitializeSecurityDescriptor`, and change its properties using the `SetSecurityDescriptorX` functions, all of which are linked from the docs for [SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's hard to say what flags you need to set in `SECURITY_INFORMATION`, because you've not indicated what keys you're trying to change, how they're configured now, and to what you want to change them.

Comment: Just to go on the record, I agree with @JonathanPotter. I also answer questions asking about how to delete things in the registry with some trepidation, because quite frequently the next question becomes "How do I fix what I screwed up?" or "Windows won't start. How do I fix it?". :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL CreateMyDACL(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES * pSA, HKEY hKey_CM_DACL)
{

    TCHAR * szSD = TEXT("D:")       
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;WD)")
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;SY)");    

     ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
                szSD,
                SDDL_REVISION_1,
                &(pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor),
                NULL);
         RegSetKeySecurity( hKey_CM_DACL, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,  pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor );
}
```